# What are the differences between Artificial Neural Networks (ANN) and Convolutional Neural Networks (CNN)

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network

It has been mentioned in many places that CNNs are very effective for Image Data compared to ANNs.

What exactly are the differences between CNN and ANN (or) what are the key advantages of CNN over ANN for Image Data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key advantages of CNN over ANN are

1. Learns **Spatial Hierarchy of Patterns** i.e., Higher Layers of CNN are formed by combining Lower Layers. This helps in identifying the Patterns more effectively than ANN
2. **Translation Invariant**: Once the CNN has learned to recognize a pattern in one location, it can recognize it in any other
   location. In short, learning (weights) can be reused even if the Image is Rotated or Shifted

All the differences between ANN and CNN are mentioned below.

I have added it as a screenshot as I want to represent the differences in a proper Tabular Format.

[image]